# Что такое recv vs recvfrom и send vs sendto?

Tags: c++

send, sendto, и sendmsg используются для пересылки сообщений в другой сокет. send можно использовать, только если сокет находится в состоянии соединения, тогда как sendto и sendmsg можно использовать в любое время.

Я хочу более детально узнать что значит в любое время.
Могу ли я отправлять сообщения без подключения к серверу, и как оно дойдет до сервера?
И могу ли я использовать только sendto и recvfrom для создания чата.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с протоколами TCP и UDP.

Comment: Я изучал немного TCP и UDP, узнал что UDP лучше чем TCP :) Но для этого, его нужно переписать под себя.
Поэтому пока меня интересует только UDP если что.

Comment: В udp само понятие *подключение* (connection) не существует... В нем вы **не можете использовать send** ([The send() call may be used only when the socket is in a connected state (so that the intended recipient is known).](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html)

Comment: Что касается чата на sendto/recvfrom -- безусловно, это можно написать, построив над UDP собственный протокол, обеспечивающий нужный именно  вам уровень надежности доставки сообщений